# Capistrano: linked file database.yml does not exist on my.server.ipadress

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, ssh, capistrano

after i try to deploy my app via capistrano to my server i get this error message:

```
DEBUG [605f198a] Finished in 0.084 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
ERROR linked file /home/deploy/myrailsapp/shared/config/database.yml does not exist on xx.xxx.xx.xxx
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as deploy@xx.xxx.xx.xxx: exit

SystemExit: exit

Tasks: TOP => deploy:check:linked_files
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: Exception while executing as deploy@xx.xxx.xx.xxx: exit
```

my deploy.rb is:

```
set :deploy_to, '/home/deploy/myrailsapp'
set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml}
set :linked_dirs, %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system}



namespace :deploy do
  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      execute :touch, release_path.join('tmp/restart.txt')
    end
  end
  after :publishing, 'deploy:restart'
  after :finishing, 'deploy:cleanup'
end


namespace :deploy do
  after :restart, :clear_cache do
    on roles(:web), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do
      # Here we can do anything such as:
      # within release_path do
      #   execute :rake, 'cache:clear'
      # end
    end
  end
end
```

i tried this tut https://www.gorails.com/deploy/ubuntu/14.04, this is my first try with capistrano.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Just create `/home/deploy/myrailsapp/shared/config/database.yml` file manually and adjust it.

Capistrano doesn't create (or manage) configuration file out of the box. So, you should do it manually or automate use own `Capistrano` scripts, `Puppet`, `Chef`, `Ansible` tools.

Comment: I've searched high and low trying to get unstuck. Your tip did the trick. Thanks @maxd.

Comment: For me I have the file but it is giving me this error. I have even opened it on vim! Why this?

Answer (score 6):

As i prefer to have my files central on the deployment server, i use this task to deploy the config files from the config dir to the linked files dir on the app server.

This uses rsync, since i use capistrano-rsync to deploy.

```
namespace :deploy do

  task :copy_config do
    on release_roles :app do |role|
      fetch(:linked_files).each do |linked_file|
        user = role.user + "@" if role.user
        hostname = role.hostname
        linked_files(shared_path).each do |file|
          run_locally do
            execute :rsync, "config/#{file.to_s.gsub(/.*\/(.*)$/,"\\1")}", "#{user}#{hostname}:#{file.to_s.gsub(/(.*)\/[^\/]*$/, "\\1")}/"
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end

end
before "deploy:check:linked_files", "deploy:copy_config"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can upload files using the rake task.

Add the gem to your Gemfile after setting up Capistrano, preferably in the :development group:

```
group :development do
  gem 'capistrano',      require: false
  gem 'capistrano-rake', require: false
end
```

Аdd it to your Capfile:

```
require 'capistrano/rake'

# Load custom tasks from `lib/capistrano/tasks` if you have any defined
Dir.glob("lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake").each { |r| import r }
```

Create file `lib/capistrano/tasks/setup.rake`  and add to it:

```
namespace :deploy do
  namespace :check do
    before :linked_files, :set_database_yml do
      on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 10 do
        upload! 'config/database.yml', "#{shared_path}/config/database.yml"
      end
    end
  end
end
```