# Git: How to create file to a certain path from terminal

Tags: git

I want to add a file to git from terminal.
Like answer to the question below, I want to create `/home/deploy/myrailsapp/shared/config/database.yml` file manually

But git touch config/database.yml not work for me 
 Anyone could help? Thanks

 [Capistrano: linked file database.yml does not exist on my.server.ipadress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28981897/capistrano-linked-file-database-yml-does-not-exist-on-my-server-ipadress)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by installing `git-extras` from https://github.com/tj/git-extras/blob/master/Installation.md

One of the commands this adds is `git touch` and as documented [here](https://github.com/tj/git-extras/blob/master/man/git-touch.md) and this does exactly what you wish:

> DESCRIPTION
>
> Call touch on the given file and add it to the current index. Used
>   one-step creating new files.

Here it is in action:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
touch config/database.yml
```

instead of

```
git touch config/database.yml
```

Comment: I want to create directly to git

Comment: By git, you mean github ?